# How can I restore a launcher in /usr/share/applications

Tags: unity, launcher, spotify

I recently messed a bit with the Spotify launcher in `/usr/share/applications`. I ended up removing the file `/usr/share/applications/spotify.desktop` from my system. I want to get back to defaults so I removed Spotify:

```
sudo apt remove --purge spotify-client
```

and afterwards I reinstalled it:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall spotify-client
```

Doing this didn't reinstall the default launcher in `/usr/share/applications`. There's nothing in `~/.local/share/applications`.

How do I get it back?

Comment: You can always manually create one in `~/.local/share/applications`: https://askubuntu.com/a/64237/480481

Comment: If when you type `spotify` in DASH and the launcher is seen check here `/usr/share/applications` to see if it's there!

Comment: @George: yes, it's actually there when I type it in. I just locked it to the launcher. But the file is still not in `/usr/share/applications`.

Comment: So follow @pomsky advice, create a new launcher for it. Feel free to do it!

Comment: Use `sudo find / -type f -iname spotify.desktop` to look for it

Comment: @Redbob please don't ask OP to create multiple `.desktop` files let OP look for where that file is

Comment: Did that. Turned out there was still a launcher in `/usr/local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/spotify`.

Comment: @George, OP told there is no Spotify launcher in `/usr/share/applications`

Comment: Possible locations for `.desktop` files are `/usr/local/share`, `~/.local/share`, and `/usr/share`.

Comment: perhaps create an answer for it, so I can mark it as answered and "close" it